# create a sendgrid list & campaign in php

Tags: php, api, post, curl, sendgrid

I tried to add emails to an existing contact list in my sendgrid account using api php, but something went wrong in my code, which returns the following message:

{"traceback": "'Traceback (most recent call last):\nFailure: exceptions.ValueError: Test does not exist\n'", "error": "Test does not exist"}

and for the create campaign button, it returns this error :

{"errors":[{"field":null,"message":"authorization required"}]}

So, have you any idea of how to create this campaign in php ?
Here is what I was trying :

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Ajax - La fonction ajax()</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
    $user = '******';
    $pass = '********';

    $params = array(
        'api_user' => $user,
        'api_key' => $pass,
        'to' => 'hjhgfr3@gmail.com',
        'subject' => 'Hello Girl !',
        'html' => 'This is me ! :D',
        'text' => 'Hello, Girl',
        'from' => 'myemail@mydomain.com',
    );

    $request = $url.'api/mail.send.json';

    // Generate curl request
    $session = curl_init($request);
?>
<button id="action">add to list</button><br /><br>
<button id="action2">Create campaign </button>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#action').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/get.json?api_user=******&api_key=********&list=Test&email@email.com',
                /* timeout: 3000,*/
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data); },
                error: function() {
                    alert('La requête n\'a pas abouti');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<script> 
    $("#action2").click(function() {
        $.get("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/campaigns?Authorization=Bearer+API-KEY",
            {
                "title": "March Newsletter",
                "subject": "New Products for Spring!",
                "sender_id": 124451,
                "list_ids": [
                    110,
                    124
                ],
                "segment_ids": [
                    110
                ],
                "categories": [
                    "spring line"
                ],
                "suppression_group_id": 42,
                "custom_unsubscribe_url": "",
                "ip_pool": "marketing",
                "html_content": "<html><head><title></title></head><body><p>Check out our spring line!</p></body></html>",
                "plain_content": "Check out our spring line!"
            },
            function(data, status){
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Kindly provide me with the functional code for adding contact to a list.

Comment: @OguguaBelonwu you can have an idea here : https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a couple of issues.

1. You are not properly authorizing. You need to set an Authorization header in your api request. 
   *Check out the docs for more info on how:* https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/index.html .
2. I see you're making GET requests, GET in this case will only retrieve data and not let you create a campaign or add to a list. You need to use POST as mentioned in the docs, https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html

*Also it might help to use an HTTP Client lib for PHP such as, [HTTPFUL](http://phphttpclient.com/#custom-headers) instead of using Curl, but whatever you prefer.*

Comment: Thank you ! This is fixed now